# Jdeveloper error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.dbtools.raptor.config.DBConfig" on start

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jdeveloper

I use Jdeveloper Studio 11.1.1.4.0, I use the ADF components on it, but for the last couple of days when I start the Jdeveloper, this Error comes up

```
Uncaught exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.dbtools.raptor.config.DBConfig
o.dbtools.raptor.oviewer.base.NavSelectionListener.viewSelectionChanged(NavSelectionListener.java:176)
o.i.view.View.fireViewSelectionChangedImpl(View.java:495)
o.i.view.ViewDecorator.fireViewSelectionChangedImpl(ViewDecorator.java:59)
o.i.view.View.fireViewSelectionChanged(View.java:485)
o.i.view.View.updateSelectionImpl0(View.java:444)
o.i.view.View.updateSelectionImpl(View.java:429)
o.i.view.View.updateSelection(View.java:306)
o.ideri.navigator.DefaultNavigatorWindow$4.viewSelectionChanged(DefaultNavigatorWindow.java:1108)
o.i.view.View.fireViewSelectionChangedImpl(View.java:495)
o.i.view.View.fireViewSelectionChanged(View.java:485)
o.i.view.View$2.actionPerformed(View.java:349)
jx.s.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:271)
jx.s.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:201)
j.a.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I can't find the Database Navigator either and also this error also comes up when I use anything related to the database, I tried to uninstall the Jdeveloper and removed the middleware folder and reinstall everything to get the default but still same story.

I really need a fix for this ASAP because I'm already behind schedule on my graduation project.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a configuration problem in your IDE. Try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

check your classpath, there must be a problem here, verify the JDevelloper folder is in